# determine column maximum value per another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains location Id, store name and store revenue. I want to determine the store that has the maximum revenue per area

I wrote a code for that, but not sure if there is a better way to handle this case

```
import pandas as pd    
dframe=pd.DataFrame({"Loc_Id":[1,2,2,1,2,1,3,3],"Store":["A","B","C","B","D","B","A","C"],
                 "Revenue":[50,70,45,35,80,70,90,65]})

#group by location id, then save max per location in new column
dframe["max_value"]=dframe.groupby("Loc_Id")["Revenue"].transform(max)

#create new column by checking if the revenue equal to max revenue
dframe["is_loc_max"]=dframe.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["Revenue"]==x["max_value"] else 0,axis=1)

#drop the intermediate column 
dframe.drop(columns=["max_value"],inplace=True)
```

and This is the required output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

is there a better way to get this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create boolean mask by compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and convert it to `integer`s - `0, 1` to `False, True`:

```
s = dframe.groupby("Loc_Id")["Revenue"].transform('max')
dframe["max_value"]= s.eq(dframe["Revenue"]).astype(int)
print (dframe)
   Loc_Id Store  Revenue  max_value
0       1     A       50          0
1       2     B       70          0
2       2     C       45          0
3       1     B       35          0
4       2     D       80          1
5       1     B       70          1
6       3     A       90          1
7       3     C       65          0
```